# The shortcuts for typing subscript is valid

Tags: formatting, keyboard, data-types

I installed the Mathematica 13.2 in my new computer， everything worked well excepted that the shortcuts for typing the subscripts "ctrl+ _" doesn't work. I tested that the "ctrl" and "-" key work well. Now if I want to type subscript, I need type superscript first and then use "ctrl+%" to generate the subscripts. I have checked the file `KeyEventTranslations.tr` and I think the settings should be right:

```
(* Typesetting input *)
    Item[KeyEvent["6", Modifiers -> {Control}], "Superscript"], 
    Item[KeyEvent["Keypad6", Modifiers -> {Control}], "Superscript"], 
    Item[KeyEvent["^", Modifiers -> {Control}], "Superscript"], 
    Item[KeyEvent["-", Modifiers -> {Control}], "Subscript"], 
    Item[KeyEvent["KeypadSubtract", Modifiers -> {Control}], "Subscript"], 
    Item[KeyEvent["_", Modifiers ->{Control}],  "Subscript"],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was related to the shortcut conflicts betwen MMA and another software in my PC, after I closed the corresponding software, the problem was solved